# Minecraft Java Spawn Zombies during the day

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

Important notes: I'm new to plugin dev; a beginner at Java; I'm using the Spigot 1.16.5 snapshot; I'm using Java 11 (this is the version my server host forces for 1.16.5 so I have to develop for Java 11, as much as I'd rather develop using the most recent version).

I want to be able to allow mobs (that only spawn at night) to spawn during the day as well. I've already got my plugin to prevent mobs from burning and dying during the day, I just can't get them to spawn during the day.

I've done many Google searches which has produced few results, literally less than one page of relevant results; the few results which are relevant to my search are not relevant to my version, with examples and advice dating as far back as 2012. I've no idea where to start with this, so I'm just asking for some guidance on how to allow the mobs to naturally spawn during the day.

In a blind attempt, I tried to check to see if the entity had been cancelled, but I understand that the mob has to exist first, so it obviously didn't work.

Any advice is appreciated.

EDIT: (Additional Information)

In my futile attempt, I used CreatureSpawnEvent and checked that the event is an instance of the mob entity, and checked that the SpawnReason was Natural. I don't know that this information will be helpful for giving advice, I just wanted to document what I have tried.

Comment: Did you look through the decompiled Minecraft source and find the code that limits zombie spawning to only happen in the dark? Does looking at it give you any clues for how to override it?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's for 1.15.2, I think [this](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/change-spawning-conditions.440970/) can help you, it requires the use NMS so you will have some trouble with multi-version support, also, [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/%E2%9A%94-mythicmobs-free-version-%E2%96%BAthe-1-custom-mob-creator%E2%97%84.5702/) is a free resource that might be able to do this if you don't manage to do it by yourself as it's pretty advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Hostile mobs will not naturally spawn if the light level is above a certain threshold. See: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Light#mobs

One possible solution is to create the illusion of it being day time by using [Player#setPlayerTime](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html#setPlayerTime(long,boolean)). 
This method can be used to make the player perceive the world as if it's day time, even if it's night time.